# How to fill in form that was produced in Word without moving the text around

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-word

We have a form that was produced in Word on which we need to fill in answers, but it doesn't have fields for filling it in.  When we try to do it on Word it moves all the letters around and messes the format up.

Is there some way to do this without typing it all again?

Answer (score 1):

Hit the <kbd>Ins</kbd> key on your keyboard before starting to fill it out.  This will switch into overwrite mode instead of inserting the text.  At the bottom of the Word window, the `OVR` box should darken to indicate the change.

Hit the key again after you are done to return it to the normal `insert` mode.